# Will aws s3 be still accessible using pre-signed urls if we create a vpc endpoint gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I have a need to add a vpc endpoint for s3 so i can access it on lambda, but when i try to create the endpoint I get a warning

> Warning

> When you use an endpoint, the source IP addresses from your instances in your affected subnets for accessing the AWS service in the same region will be private IP addresses, not public IP addresses. Existing connections from your affected subnets to the AWS service that use public IP addresses may be dropped. Ensure that you don’t have critical tasks running when you create or modify an endpoint.

Here I am not sure what it means exactly.

Can I be able to access s3 publicly?

currently i put objects to s3 using pre-signed urls, can I be able to continue to using it after creating a vpc endpoint (which is private)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: adding a VPC endpoint doesn't prevent an S3 bucket being accessed over the internet.

That message means the S3 access logs will show the instance private IP rather than public IPs. Any existing connections from instances to S3 may be dropped when you add the endpoint. I don't think this is likely to be an issue, but I would make the change during an outage window or outside peak usage hours, depending what the workload is.

Comment: Thankyou @Tim you yes it is exactly like that.